# Solr json import performance issue (solr hangs on large files)

Tags: json, curl, solr

I have some json files of various sizes (4 -> 100MB) & importing into Solr 5.0.0 using this command:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/some-index/update?commit=true' --data-binary @"data.json" -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

The import process take long time (minutes) for each file. After some imports, Solr hangs and needs a restart.

Do anyone have experience on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: are  you monitoring the CPU/memory/swap of the "hung" machine? Keep a separate window open and run top and/or vmstat to track what is happening. Very likely if you let the "hung" process work (possibly for a long time it will "unhang". What you describe is common to systems that create lots of indexes. To really avoid this, you'll have to study the solr doc for memory tuning tips for indexes and decide if you really need all of the indexes you currently have. Recall that what ever time it takes to process 1 MB, will be at least N times longer for 10,100,1000 MBs. There is no easy solution :-/

Comment: ah, solr heap size is set too low (512MB by default, that's cause the problem). But i still wonder why json index is taking too long time to process (even with file size 1-2MB)

Comment: In my middle-level experience with search indexing, these issues haunt you for a long time. Once you have X amount of data in a solr instance, and things slow up, you either have to create a new instance for more data, or go back, reduce what you're indexing, reindex, and then load new data. You may find a fix but it will likely be the result of learning proper monitoring/metrics/config management . (As is, you don't give any http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to work with on this problem). Good luck!